# access error "sub or function not defined"

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an error in VBA access running.
When I run this code

```
Option Compare Database

Function Ashray()

Dim last As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim column As Integer
Dim temp As String

column = 2
i = 1

While i > 0
temp = ws.Cells(i, column).Value
last = Right(temp, 4)
ws.Cells(i, 1).offset(, column).Value = last
i = i + 1
If ws.Cells(i, column).Value < 1 Then
i = 0
End If

Wend
End Function
```

I get the error `Run-time Error '424': Object Required` with the `temp = ws.Cells(i, column).Value` bold.

I will be happy for some help..

Thanks

Comment: Do you actually have an Excel worksheet? Where is it defined? What is this function supposed to do? --- It seems you have copied code written for Excel to Access, it doesn't work like that.

Comment: I wrote all this code by myself. It's supposed to take a column, cell by cell, of credit card numbers and write in the cell near to it, the 4 last digits.

Comment: Ok. But in Access there are no cells. If your data is in a **table**, your task can be done with a simple UPDATE query, using the `Right()` function.

Comment: Add `Option Explicit` on the line after `Option Compare Database` and fix everything the compiler complains about.

Comment: @HansUp thanks but It still give an error "variable not defined" on and the "ws" bold

Comment: @DvirNaim: please clarify: is your data in an **Access table** or in an **Excel worksheet**?

Comment: Have down-voted as we still don't know if it's an Access table or Excel worksheet - the OP doesn't seem to want to supply that vital bit of information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Cells` is an Excel object, it doesn't exist in Access.

If you have a worksheet variable, use it as qualifier:

```
ws.Cells
```

Comment: Thanks! It works! But there is still an error - "Run-time Error '424': Object Required"

Comment: @DvirNaim: What works? Please edit your question and update the code. And indicate the line where the error occurs.

Comment: Hi. Thanks again. Done

Answer (score 0):

Please check your code

```
While i
 temp = Cells(i, column).Value
 last = Right(temp, 4)
 Cells(i, 1).offset(, column).Value = last
 i = i + 1
 If Cells(i, column).Value < 1 Then
 i = 0
End If
**Wend**
```

This is not the Wend, this might be End While.

Regards
Jasbeer Singh

Comment: Hi! First of all - big thanks for your answer. It Doesn't let me write End While. And even if write just End It still an error.

Comment: That's not the problem. `While i ... Wend` is syntactically ok, although it would be better readable to write `While i <> 0 ... Wend`. -- `End While` doesn't even exist.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to add an Microsoft Excel 15.0 Object Library reference in your project (Tools> References and then check the library I mentionned).
Then try to instanciate an Excel Object as follow:

```
Option Compare Database

Function Ashray()

Dim last As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim column As Integer
Dim temp As String
Dim ws As Excel.Application
Dim wsht as ws.Workbook

Set wsht = Workbooks("yourWorkbook.xls").Sheets("yourSheet")
column = 2
i = 1

While i > 0
temp = wsht.Cells(i, column).Value
last = Right(temp, 4)
wsht.Cells(i, 1).offset(, column).Value = last
i = i + 1
If wsht.Cells(i, column).Value < 1 Then
i = 0
End If
Wend

End Function
```

You have to add the library to the Access project, else it will not find the Excel workbook you're trying to access.

Regards.